# Having trouble in displaying UITableView

Tags: iphone

Please see

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];




UILabel *playerHeading=[[UILabel alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 10.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f)];
[playerHeading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player %i",indexPath.row];
[playerHeading setText:str];
[playerHeading setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];

if(indexPath.section%2==0){
    playerHeading.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
else {
    playerHeading.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];

}

UITextField *txt=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0f, 13.0f, 170.0f, 30.0f)];
[txt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


//[txt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[txt setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
txt.delegate=self;
//[txt setBorderStyle:UIBorderStyle ]
[txt setText:@"Enter Player name"];
//txt.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
   //   txt.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
//txt.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
   //   txt.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

[cell.contentView addSubview:txt];

[cell.contentView addSubview:playerHeading];

[cell.contentView setAlpha:0.8f];
//ce]ll.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
}
return cell;
```

}

I want to display the number in sequence like Player 0, Player 1, Player 2...
but as I scroll the table i get numbers in random format like Player 1, Player 0 ,Player 3 
Please help how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the labels as new subviews all the time - this means you will have label above label above label, which is a waste of memory as well as a potential source of display issues.

When you create your cells (inside `if (cell == nil)` create and add the subviews at that point, and assign each one a tag. Then configure them all outside that loop. An example just with your `playerHeading` label:

```
UILabel *playerHeading;

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    playerHeading=[[UILabel alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 10.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f)];
    [playerHeading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [playerHeading setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
    [playerHeading setTag:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:playerHeading];
}
else
{
    playerHeading = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
}

playerHeading.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player %i",indexPath.row];
```

You do appear to have more than one section in your table (you have an `if` statement on indexPath.section) so your player numbers will start again from 0 in each section with the above code.

Comment: But i have used TextFields dynamically ,how can retrieve their values if i am trying to add them is an array ,array would have 8 TextFields max: though I used 100

Comment: You'd do the same with your textfields but would keep the string values (not the fields) in an array, and update each time. When editing the text field, get the index path of the row that you are editing, so you know which element of the array to update.

Answer (score 0):

try to close the {} of the if(cell == nil) earlier like here:

```
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease]; 
}
```

Comment: used but it creates data duplication